# Parse - Get object from pointer on beforeSave?

Tags: parse-platform

I have an Offer object that I send to the server, when this offer is about to be created I need to send a push notification to the user. Offer has a pointer to User an the field is called "to".

**How can I fetch an object from a pointer?**

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Request", function(request, response) {

    var userQuery = new Parse.Query("User")

    userQuery.get(request.object.get("to").id, {
        success: function (user) {
            console.log("user: ", user);
            var installationQuery = new Parse.Query("Installation");
            installationQuery.equalTo("user", user);

            Parse.Push.send({
                where : installationQuery,
                data : {
                    alert : "HEllo"
                },
                success : function() {

                },
                error : function() {
                    console.log("error finding installation: " + error);
                }
            });
        },
        error : function (error) {
            console.log("ERRRRRRRRRR");
        }
    });

    response.success();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can use [Parse.Query.get()](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#get) or [Parse.Object.fetch()](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#fetch) to retrieve the object.

I'm assuming that the problem you see is that the object saves but the push notification isn't happening. The cause is that you're not waiting for the get() to complete before calling response.success() and returning.

Here's a couple ways to reconcile that:

Your existing code but with response.success() moved up:
    Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Request", function(request, response) {

```
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query("User")

    userQuery.get(request.object.get("to").id, {
        success: function (user) {
            console.log("user: ", user);
            var installationQuery = new Parse.Query("Installation");
            installationQuery.equalTo("user", user);

            Parse.Push.send({
                where : installationQuery,
                data : {
                    alert : "HEllo"
                },
                success : function() {
                    response.success();
                },
                error : function() {
                    console.log("error finding installation: " + error);
                }
            });
        },
        error : function (error) {
            console.log("ERRRRRRRRRR");
        }
    });
});
```

Simplified with [Promises](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Promise.html)

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Request", function(request, response) {
    request.object.get("to").fetch().then(function(user) {
        var installationQuery = new Parse.Query("Installation");
        installationQuery.equalTo("user", user);

        return Parse.Push.send({
            where : installationQuery,
            data : {
                alert : "HEllo"
            }
        });
    }).then(function() {
        response.success();
    }, response.error);
});
```

Further simplified. If you're not using the data within user, you shouldn't need to fetch it just to pass a pointer to a query.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Request", function(request, response) {
    var installationQuery = new Parse.Query("Installation");
    installationQuery.equalTo("user", request.object.get("to"));

    return Parse.Push.send({
        where : installationQuery,
        data : {
            alert : "HEllo"
        }
    }).then(function() {
        response.success();
    }, response.error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I believe I tried the last portion of code already, and it didn't work, I think it's because the query result was empty. Will try it again when I get home, and will post a response.